# How to get the size (total memory) used for each cached key item in Ignite.NET (C#)?

Tags: .net, ignite, gridgain

Is there anyway to get the size (total memory) used for each cache key item in Ignite.NET (C#)? The current method `GetSize()` provides the total number of cache entries in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Finding out memory usage for a particular entry isn't really possible because of how the memory footprint is structured. Whenever you add an entry, you'll consume

- A chunk of memory in the data pages; there is overhead and fragmentation in the data pages too, so that adds on top
- For every index you have, a chunk of memory for the new index tree leaf + some (tiny) amount of memory will additionally be used by the index tree
- There are some internal data structures that also will be changed and consume tiny amounts of additional memory

So, instead of trying to understand the size of a particular entry, you normally want to understand the total used size of a data region. You can then divide that by the number of entries in the region to get the average entry size.

[Here](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.IDataRegionMetrics.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_IDataRegionMetrics_TotalUsedPages) is the interface with the data region metrics.

To get the amount of memory currently occupied by all caches of the data region, you need to calculate `TotalUsedPages * PageSize`.